# Nested JSON Schema Validation in Postman

Tags: json, validation, nested, schema, postman

I want to validate a **Nested JSON Schema** in **Postman**.

Here is the code.

```
const testSchema = {
    "name": [
        {
            "first_name": "Alpha",
            "last_name": "Bravo"
        },
        {
            "first_name": "Charlie",
            "last_name": "Delta"
        },
    ],
    "age": "23",
    "color": "black"
};

const showData = { 
    "required": ["name", "age"],
    "properties": {
        "name": [
            {
                "required": ["first_name"]
            }
        ],
    },
};

pm.test("Nested Schema Test", function () {
    pm.expect(tv4.validate(testSchema, showData)).to.be.true;
});
```

Currently, this code returns test as **true**.

I am unable to test the **"name"** *array objects' keys*.

Even upon passing this:

`"required": ["fst_nae"] //wrong key name`

it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

I would just check in easy way via:

```
pm.test("your name", function () {
   pm.expect(testSchema.name[0].first_name && testSchema.name[1].first_name
   ).to.eql('Alpha' && 'Charlie') 
});
```

and you successfully validated these fields 
or use this expect to organize your code of your choice

Answer (score 0):

tiny validator i.e. `tv4.validate` is having issues in their library. Another option is to use `AJV` (you can search it on github).

Comment: Please try to provide github link for the library. try to provide detail information